# How to setup unprivileged LXC container without reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, lxc

I am writing some bootstrapping scripts, and I can't get usermode LXC containers working on vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 headless without a reboot.

Here is what i do.

First, I download and install [Ubuntu server 14.04.1 amd64](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso) with everything default on a fresh (virtual guest under VirtualBox) machine.

Then I log in, and update & upgrade it, and reboot if the kernel got upgraded.

Then I log in, and issue the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get --yes install lxc
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bridge-utils cgmanager cloud-image-utils debootstrap distro-info
  distro-info-data dnsmasq-base euca2ools genisoimage libaio1
  libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 liblxc1 libmnl0
  libnetfilter-conntrack3 librados2 librbd1 libseccomp2 libxslt1.1
  lxc-templates python-distro-info python-lxml python-requestbuilder
  python-setuptools python3-lxc qemu-utils sharutils uidmap
Suggested packages:
  cgmanager-utils shunit2 wodim cdrkit-doc lxctl qemu-user-static
  python-lxml-dbg bsd-mailx mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bridge-utils cgmanager cloud-image-utils debootstrap distro-info
  distro-info-data dnsmasq-base euca2ools genisoimage libaio1
  libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 liblxc1 libmnl0
  libnetfilter-conntrack3 librados2 librbd1 libseccomp2 libxslt1.1 lxc
  lxc-templates python-distro-info python-lxml python-requestbuilder
  python-setuptools python3-lxc qemu-utils sharutils uidmap
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 5219 kB of archives.

...

$ rm -rf /home/zosia/.config/lxc /home/zosia/.local/share/lxc
$ sudo mkdir /opt/lxc
$ sudo chown -R zosia /opt/lxc
$ mkdir /opt/lxc/config /opt/lxc/store
$ ln -s /opt/lxc/store /home/zosia/.local/share/lxc
$ ln -s /opt/lxc/config /home/zosia/.config/lxc
$ sudo usermod --add-subuids 100000-165536 zosia
$ sudo usermod --add-subgids 100000-165536 zosia
$ sudo chmod +x /home/zosia
$ tee /home/zosia/.config/lxc/default.conf <<EOT
lxc.include = /etc/lxc/default.conf
lxc.id_map = u 0 100000 65536
lxc.id_map = g 0 100000 65536
EOT

$ echo 'zosia veth lxcbr0 10' | sudo tee -a /etc/lxc/lxc-usernet
zosia veth lxcbr0 10

$ mkdir -p /home/zosia/.cache/lxc
$ sudo chmod -R +x /home/zosia/.local
$ lxc-create -t download -n usik -- -d ubuntu -r trusty -a amd64
Setting up the GPG keyring
Downloading the image index
Downloading the rootfs
Downloading the metadata
The image cache is now ready
Unpacking the rootfs

---
You just created an Ubuntu container (release=trusty, arch=amd64, variant=default)

To enable sshd, run: apt-get install openssh-server

For security reason, container images ship without user accounts
and without a root password.

Use lxc-attach or chroot directly into the rootfs to set a root password
or create user accounts.

$ lxc-start -n usik
lxc_container: call to cgmanager_create_sync failed: invalid request
lxc_container: Failed to create hugetlb:usik
lxc_container: Error creating cgroup hugetlb:usik
lxc_container: failed creating cgroups
lxc_container: failed to spawn 'usik'
lxc_container: The container failed to start.
lxc_container: Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

Unless the host is rebooted after all these commands, the `lxc-start -n usik` throws an error. Restarting service `lxc`, `lxc-net` or `cgmanager` doesn't help either.

The logfile says the following:

```
  lxc-start 1418283881.262 INFO     lxc_start_ui - using rcfile /home/zosia/.local/share/lxc/usik/config
  lxc-start 1418283881.262 INFO     lxc_confile - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
  lxc-start 1418283881.262 INFO     lxc_confile - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
  lxc-start 1418283881.263 WARN     lxc_log - lxc_log_init called with log already initialized
  lxc-start 1418283881.263 INFO     lxc_lsm - LSM security driver AppArmor
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_conf - allocated pty '/dev/pts/1' (5/6)
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_conf - allocated pty '/dev/pts/6' (7/8)
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_conf - allocated pty '/dev/pts/7' (9/10)
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_conf - allocated pty '/dev/pts/8' (11/12)
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 INFO     lxc_conf - tty's configured
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_start - sigchild handler set
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_console - opening /dev/tty for console peer
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_console - using '/dev/tty' as console
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_console - 3809 got SIGWINCH fd 17
  lxc-start 1418283881.264 DEBUG    lxc_console - set winsz dstfd:14 cols:151 rows:41
  lxc-start 1418283881.309 INFO     lxc_start - 'usik' is initialized
  lxc-start 1418283881.309 DEBUG    lxc_start - Not dropping cap_sys_boot or watching utmp
  lxc-start 1418283881.309 INFO     lxc_start - Cloning a new user namespace
  lxc-start 1418283881.309 INFO     lxc_cgroup - cgroup driver cgmanager initing for usik
  lxc-start 1418283881.310 ERROR    lxc_cgmanager - call to cgmanager_create_sync failed: invalid request
  lxc-start 1418283881.311 ERROR    lxc_cgmanager - Failed to create hugetlb:usik
  lxc-start 1418283881.311 ERROR    lxc_cgmanager - Error creating cgroup hugetlb:usik
  lxc-start 1418283881.312 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: hugetlb:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.312 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: perf_event:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.312 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: blkio:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.312 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: freezer:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.313 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: devices:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.313 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: memory:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.313 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: cpuacct:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.313 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: cpu:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.313 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: cpuset:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.313 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgroup removal attempt: name=systemd:usik did not exist
  lxc-start 1418283881.313 ERROR    lxc_start - failed creating cgroups
  lxc-start 1418283881.314 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to spawn 'usik'
  lxc-start 1418283881.315 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - The container failed to start.
  lxc-start 1418283881.315 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be (just a guess), [turning user_namespaces on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303213/4319) would be of some help in your situation:

```
sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart dbus. You will have to log out and back in (I was using SSH), but it sets up the cgroups properly and you will be able to start the container without rebooting the whole server.

If you don't want to log out and back in, you can try to create cgroups manually with cgm as explained here https://linuxcontainers.org/cgmanager/getting-started/ . I was able to start a container, but I wasn't able to use it anymore after logging out and back in as the cgroups that I created manually were different from the ones created automatically upon login.