# How to enable user_namespaces in the kernel? (For unprivileged `unshare`.)

Tags: security, non-root-user, sysctl, userns, altlinux

My Linux kernel must have been configured with [user_namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html) when built, but their use is restricted after boot and has to be explicitly enabled. Which sysctl should I use?

(If this was turned on, this would allow to run an isolation command like `unshare --user --map-root-user --mount-proc --pid --fork`, and then perform [`chroot` without being root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72696/4319)--a much anticipated feature of Linux.)

Comment: See also the same question (regarding Debian): https://superuser.com/q/1094597/65570

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Debian-based Linux

Debian (and hence probably Ubuntu, too) has been known to ship a kernel with such a restriction of user_namespaces, and there the way to enable it was/is:

```
sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

(Source: https://blog.mister-muffin.de/2015/10/25/unshare-without-superuser-privileges/.)

Since kernel 5.10 (Debian 11/bullseye), Debian [enables unprivileged user namespaces by default](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#linux-user-namespaces); if you find they're still disabled, also check the sysctl `user.max_user_namespaces` (which, unlike `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone`, is not Debian-specific).

## ALT-Linux Specific

ALT has such a restriction in [kernel-image-std-def](https://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/kernel-image-std-def/patches), too. Differently from Debian, it's called `kernel.userns_restrict`.

Normally, it is 1 (i.e., "restricted"):

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/userns_restrict 
1
```

To enable this, `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/userns_restrict` (or use `sysctl` as above, of course).

Comment: Or, for a permanent solution: `echo 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/userns.conf`

Comment: I'd say ```echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/userns_restrict``` to enable ?!

Comment: @tisc0 No, the sense is opposite in Debian and ALT. In Debian it's `1` to enable the unpriviledged use of it; in ALT, it's `0` **not to restrict** its use.

Comment: Why not just use the same name and default it to true, ie `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1`